# Debug.Print VBA collection of dates type mismatch error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a collection of dates and am trying to print them but get a type mismatch error, not sure how to solve it, have tried setting the item as an object but still getting the error.
Here is the code:

```
        Sub Test_Dates()
        '
        Dim TESTWB As Workbook
        Dim TESTWS As Worksheet
        
        Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
        Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")
        
        Dim DatesTest As New Collection
        Const FirstRow As Long = 2
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = FirstRow To LastRow
              DatesTest.Add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))
        Next i
        
        Dim item As Variant
        
    For Each item In DatesTest

    Dim nDate As Variant
    
        For Each nDate In item
        
        Debug.Print item(nDate)
        
        Next nDate
        
    
Next item
        

        
        End Sub
```

This is the getDates function i am using above

```
Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

Dim varDates()      As Date
Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
    varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
    StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
Next lngDateCounter

getDates = varDates

ClearMemory:
    If IsArray(varDates) Then Erase varDates
    lngDateCounter = Empty

End Function
```

Comment: `getDates` does this return an array?  you will need to loop the returned array, so item(0) for array item 0 in your example if getDates does return an array

Comment: In vba, some object can't be printed. I idvice you to replace `Debug.Print item` with `Debug.Print typename(item)` to see the type of the item, and after knowing the type, you can get the value you want

Comment: @NASSIMADRAO the item type is date()

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes getDates returns an array, ok yes will try that tks

Comment: `date()` indicates that you get an array of date, so you have to loop on the `item` with another for each
Hope it works

Comment: @Nathan_Sav See my edit, doesnt return a Date, have also tried for each nDate but it gives a type mismatch not sure why

Comment: `item`, from `datestest` is an array we established earlier, so `datestest.count` won't return what you need as that is the count of the collection, you need to use `ubound(item)` i believe

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, but For nDate = 0 To UBound(DatesTest) wont work either, so am not sure how to print nDate in this case, because it is not set up as an array

Comment: For Each nDate In item Debug.Print item(nDate) (see my edit) have tried this but no success

Comment: `Debug.Print nDate` for your current code version

Comment: @Rory thanks, was looking at this too much, lost the plot. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Dim item As Variant
>
> For Each item In DatesTest
>
>     Dim nDate As Variant
>
>     For nDate = 0 To DatesTest.Count
>     
>         Debug.Print nDate
>     
>     Next nDate
>
> Next item
> ```

I am not sure what your getDates function is doing, but to access the items in a collection all you need is the variant. It would be done like this:

```
Dim nDate as Variant
For Each nDate in DatesTest
    Debug.Print nDate
Next nDate
```

I assume the rest of that code is trying to handle the return of getDates(). However, this code does not need to reference the collection; that was already done by the for each loop. Within the for loop you need to process each item from the collection.

Without seeing the coding for the getDates function, it would be difficult to address the extra coding to handle printing of each variant within the collection.

> ```
> Dim nDate As Variant
>
>     For nDate = 0 To DatesTest.Count
>     
>     Debug.Print nDate
>     
>     Next nDate
> ```

This loop will print the numbers 0 to DatesTest.Count for each item in the collection. It does not print the item itself.

Additionally, you can step through the subroutine to find the line that is causing the error (F8).

### **A WORD OF CAUTION**

This program can take a long time to process and use a large amount of memory depending on the difference in dates and number of rows in the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Dates()
    Dim TESTWB As Workbook
    Dim TESTWS As Worksheet
        
    Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")
        
    Dim DatesTest As New Collection
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = TESTWS.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        DatesTest.Add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))
    Next i
        
    Dim item As Variant
        
    For Each item In DatesTest
        Dim nDate As Variant
        For Each nDate In item
            Debug.Print nDate
        Next nDate
    Next item
End Sub

Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

Dim varDates() As Date
Dim lngDateCounter As Long

ReDim varDates(0 To (EndDate - StartDate))

For lngDateCounter = 0 To UBound(varDates)
    varDates(lngDateCounter) = StartDate
    StartDate = StartDate + 1
Next lngDateCounter

getDates = varDates

ClearMemory:
    If IsArray(varDates) Then Erase varDates
End Function
```

The scope of varDates and lngDateCounter ends with the function return so it was not really needed to erase but I left the erasure of the dynamic array for good measure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, added the function see my edit

Comment: indeed quite slow, any ideas for speed improvement?

Comment: Without knowing more of how this is being utilized, it is hard to redesign this program to perform faster. What is the need to have a collection with all inclusive dates within multiple ranges stored in this way?